# Retrieving information from batch request in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-api

Here is a sample batch request response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_pK7JBAk73-E=_AA5eFwv4m2Q=
Date: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 18:56:00 GMT
Expires: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 18:56:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0

--batch_pK7JBAk73-E=_AA5eFwv4m2Q=
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-TIMELINE_INSERT_USER_1

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 304

{
 "kind": "glass#timelineItem",
 "id": "1234567890",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/1234567890",
 "created": "2012-09-25T23:28:43.192Z",
 "updated": "2012-09-25T23:28:43.192Z",
 "etag": "\"G5BI0RWvj-0jWdBrdWrPZV7xPKw/t25selcGS3uDEVT6FB09hAG-QQ\"",
 "text": "Hello there!"
}
--batch_pK7JBAk73-E=_AA5eFwv4m2Q=
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-TIMELINE_INSERT_USER_2

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 304

{
 "kind": "glass#timelineItem",
 "id": "0987654321",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/0987654321",
 "created": "2012-09-25T23:28:43.192Z",
 "updated": "2012-09-25T23:28:43.192Z",
 "etag": "\"G5BI0RWvj-0jWdBrdWrPZV7xPKw/t25selcGS3uDEVT6FB09hAG-QQ\"",
 "text": "Hello there!"
}
--batch_pK7JBAk73-E=_AA5eFwv4m2Q=
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-TIMELINE_INSERT_USER_3

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 304

{
 "kind": "glass#timelineItem",
 "id": "5432109876",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/5432109876",
 "created": "2012-09-25T23:28:43.192Z",
 "updated": "2012-09-25T23:28:43.192Z",
 "etag": "\"G5BI0RWvj-0jWdBrdWrPZV7xPKw/t25selcGS3uDEVT6FB09hAG-QQ\"",
 "text": "Hello there!"
}
--batch_pK7JBAk73-E=_AA5eFwv4m2Q=--
```

I have a similar looking response with my batch request, but I'm having trouble getting each batch's `kind`. How can I retrieve each batch's '`kind`??

**Edit**

I'm getting a similar response using Googl's Batch Request.

```
gclient = Google::APIClient.new(....)

batch = Google::APIClient::BatchRequest.new
batch.add(list_salesman_one).add(list_salesman_two)
batch = gclient.execute(batch).to_json
batch_decoded = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(batch)  OR    batch_decoded = JSON.parse(batch)
batch_decoded_body = batch_decoded["response"]["body"]
```

Where `batch_decoded_body` gives me the response above. The `OR` in the variable `batch_decoded` means that I can use either one.

Comment: What are you using to get this data in the first place?  Ie what's the code and are you using any gems eg nokogiri to do it?

Comment: OK, I added an update with the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle each entry in your batch separately:

1. Separate batch to entries:

   ```
   entries = batch_decoded_body.strip.split(/^--.*/)
   ```
2. The first entry is not really an entry, but a header, so you can get rid of it:

   ```
   entries.shift
   ```
3. For each entry parse to a JSON, starting from `{`:

   ```
   entries.map { |entry| JSON.parse entry[/{.*/m] }
   ```

All together:

```
entries = batch_decoded_body.strip.split(/^--.*/)
entries.shift
entries.map { |entry| JSON.parse(entry[/{.*/m])['kind'] }
# => ["glass#timelineItem", "glass#timelineItem", "glass#timelineItem"] 
entries.map { |entry| JSON.parse(entry[/{.*/m])['items'].map { |item| item['ipAddress'] } }
# => [["IP_ADDRESS_HERE"], ["IP_ADDRESS_HERE"]]
```

Comment: Getting the error `no implicit conversion of nil into String`

Comment: The `shift` returns nothing.

Comment: @Justin - I'm guessing your boundary has changed? I updated my answer to lookup the actual boundary. `batch_decoded_body` looks like what you posted at the start of the post, right?

Comment: Yes it does. This this is now giving me a `JSON::ParserError` with this output: `399: unexpected token at '{ "kind": "admin#reports#activity", "id": { "time": "2014-05-01T18:53:26.000Z", "uniqueQualifier": "-9812474215432855919", "applicationName": "login", "customerId": "C72lromre" }, "etag": "\"KOlSfwDlwRtCXIpAq5lLGkjWDc36DY/dRnP'`

Comment: Could you put the whole string which fails in a bitbucket or something?

Comment: Alright here is a gist. I'm trying to get each entry's ipAddress. The example above was just to understand how it's done with basic implementation. This is the `batch_decoded_body` https://gist.github.com/licatajustin/184c6bdef1d11dcd8a0d

Comment: It is missing the first entry (which defines the boundary)

Comment: Alright, I will update it with the *entire* batch ( `client.execute(batch).to_json`)

Comment: @Justin - I've removed the boundary check, since it is not part of the body, but I added `^` (line begin) to my split, which should solve your `ParseError` problem. Also added query for `items.ipAddress`.

Comment: Where did you start from?? The error is still there.

Comment: Altogether, starting from executing the batch I have `batch = gclient.execute(batch).to_json
    batch_decoded = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(batch)
    batch_decoded_body  = batch_decoded["response"]["body"]
    entries = batch_decoded_body.split(/^--.*/)
    entries.shift
    entries.map { |entry| JSON.parse(entry[/{.*/m])['items'].map { |item| item['ipAddress'] } }`

Comment: @Justin - There was a trailing new-line - solved it with a `batch_decoded_body.strip`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into the json library.  Example:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

request = open('http://ip.jsontest.com')
response = JSON.parse(request.read)
response["ip"]
```

You could use JSON.parse to read your response (I'll assume it's in a variable called response):

```
require 'json'
response_json = JSON.parse(response)
response_json['kind']
```

Comment: Yea that's what I had originally, but the response is a string. Therefore, calling `response_json["kind"]` will just output the string `kind`

Answer (score 0):

If your response is exactly like you have it above, say stored in a variable called str and you want to exctract the kinds as string array, you can do the following:

```
arr = str.scan(/\{.*?kind.*?\}/m)
puts arr
```